# Redesign of a <li>-element

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I'd like to include a `<ul>`-element within a `<li>`-element, but I do not know how to do it. I tried to describe the problem in a simple and understandable way. I suspect it is only a small place, which must be adapted.
I am using XSLT 1.0.

Here is the given XML:

```
<University>
    <Student>
        <Info>Example 1.0</Info>
        <Details>
            <Entry>
                <Info>Example 1.1</Info>
            </Entry>
            <Entry>
                <Info>Example 1.2</Info>
            </Entry>
        </Details>
    </Student>
    <Student>
        <Info>Example 2.0</Info>
    </Student>
    <Student>
        <Info>Example 3.0</Info>
    </Student>
</University>
```

What I want should look like this:

```
<div>
    <p data-role="heading">UNIVERSITY</p>
    <ul>
        <li>Example 1.0
            <ul>
                <li>Example 1.1</li>
                <li>Example 1.2</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>Example 2.0</li>
        <li>Example 3.0</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

What I get at the moment is the following code:

```
<div>
    <p data-role="heading">UNIVERSITY</p>
    <ul>
        <li>Example 1.0</li>
        <ul>
            <li>Example 1.1</li>
            <li>Example 1.2</li>
        </ul>
        <li>Example 2.0</li>
        <li>Example 3.0</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

My XSLT looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
                xmlns:nxps="urn:nxps"
                exclude-result-prefixes="nxps">
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
  <!-- UNIVERSITY -->
    <xsl:template match="University">
        <div>
            <!-- HEADING -->
            <p data-role="heading">
                <xsl:text>UNIVERSITY</xsl:text>
            </p>
            <ul>
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </xsl:template>
    <!-- STUDENT -->
    <xsl:template match="Student">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>
    <!-- INFO IN STUDENT & ENTRY -->
    <xsl:template match="Entry/Info | Student/Info">
        <xsl:choose>
            <!-- FIRST INFO -->
            <xsl:when test="name(preceding-sibling::*[1])!='Info'">
                <li>
                    <xsl:apply-templates/>
                </li>
            </xsl:when>
            <!-- FOLLOWING INFO -->
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <li class="Parablock">
                    <xsl:apply-templates/>
                </li>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
    <!-- DETAILS -->
    <xsl:template match="Details">
        <ul>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </ul>
    </xsl:template>
    <!-- ENTRY -->
    <xsl:template match="Entry">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Here is also a link to the .NET XSLT Fiddle: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/eiZQaG5/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need a template that matches `Student` nodes which have a child `Details` node

```
<xsl:template match="Student[Details]">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="Info" />
</xsl:template>
```

Then, in your template matching `Student/Info` you can select any following `Details` node so that it is output as a nested element in the `li`

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::*[1][self::Details]" />
```

Try this XSLT, in which I have also simplified the `Student/Info` template:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
                xmlns:nxps="urn:nxps"
                exclude-result-prefixes="nxps">

    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

    <!-- UNIVERSITY -->
    <xsl:template match="University">
        <div>
            <!-- HEADING -->
            <p data-role="heading">
                <xsl:text>UNIVERSITY</xsl:text>
            </p>
            <ul>
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- STUDENT -->
    <xsl:template match="Student">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Student[Details]">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Info" />
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- INFO IN STUDENT & ENTRY -->
    <xsl:template match="Entry/Info | Student/Info">
        <li>
            <xsl:if test="name(preceding-sibling::*[1]) = 'Info'">
                <xsl:attribute name="class">Parablok</xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::*[1][self::Details]" />
        </li>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- DETAILS -->
    <xsl:template match="Details">
        <ul>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </ul>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- ENTRY -->
    <xsl:template match="Entry">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note you could actually remove the "Student" and "Entry" templates because XSLT's built-in templates would do exactly the same thing in this case.

Comment: Yea that's it. Thank you Tim.